# Echoed paragraph goes out of div boundary and should be centered

Tags: php, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WDzr.png)

Hello am having this code with an echo of h3 and p tags from the database am having an issue that the paragraph goes out of the boundary of the nested div

Here is an image of the issue am having while fetching the paragraph and the h3
https://postimg.cc/7Jy0ZJpg

and this is how i want to make it
this is just a simple html/css test
https://postimg.cc/1VfXPmzp

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the output lines do not have spaces, so they do not fit into the container. The CSS `word-break: break-all` property should fix this. You can check examples in docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break